# Saving has_many, :through associations when there are extra attributes in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

This question seems to have been asked many times before, but I didn't see it satisfactorily answered anywhere.

I have three tables/models:

```
skill
----------------------------------
id
label


user
----------------------------------
id
username
(many other irrelevant attributes)


user_skill
----------------------------------
id
user_id
skill_id
current_proficiency_level
interest_level
```

So each user has any number of skills, and each user can indicate how proficient he is with that skill right now (maybe I'm a 2 with PHP) and then what your interest level is (but maybe I want to learn PHP, so my interest level is an 8).

I'm wondering what the simplest, "most default" way of saving these `UserSkill` records is.

Let's not worry right now about the format in which my `User` object is getting the `UserSkill` records. Let's just assume that I have some user and I want to save, say, 10 `UserSkill` records when I save my `User` object. How would I do that?

(By the way, I'm reasonably well-versed with Rails in general, I just haven't bothered yet to figure out the "right" way to do this kind of save. So if you reference other Rails terms/practices, I'll probably know what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing `@user.user_skills = (values)`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `has_many :through` is used if the join table is going to be manipulated.

See here, for example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

In either case, you would add Skills to a User the same way: `@user.skills << a_skill_object` or `@user.skills = array_of_skill_objects` (this would remove any skills already associated with the `@user`).

The attributes on the join table can be set manually after the association is made: `@user.user_skills.first.current_proficiency_level = 42`